# How can I get the contents of a JavaFX TableColumn?

Tags: java, javafx

If I have a TableView in JavaFX with some TableColumn's is there a way I can get the data in that column's cells?

```
TableColumn concentrationCol = new TableColumn("Initial Concentration");
    concentrationCol.setMinWidth(150);
    concentrationCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<SpeciesDoubleWrapper, String>("d"));
    concentrationCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    concentrationCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SpeciesDoubleWrapper, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<SpeciesDoubleWrapper, String> t) {
                    ((SpeciesDoubleWrapper) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setD(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
    );
```

This is the code I use to create my TableColumn. I know there is a function `getCellObservableValue(int i)` which returns the contents of the ith cell, but when I use it I get `ObjectProperty [value: 0.0]` returned instead of `0.0`, which is the value of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getValue` method of extended class `ObjectExpression`:

```
getCellObservableValue(0).getValue()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ObjectExpression.html#getValue--

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a [`Property`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html), and more precisely an [`ObjectProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html).

These classes are used for the concept of [data binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm). To make it short, data binding allows JavaFX to keep track of the values if they change and automatically update the view accordingly.

To get the value, just call [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableObjectValue.html#get--).